# AndroidStudio, java.util.zip.ZipException

Tags: android, android-studio, zipexception

I have two test phones, one is Samsung Galaxy S5, and the other one is LG G2.

Whenever I try to run my app on LG G2, I have following error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: 
com/google/android/gms/gcm/PendingCallback.class
```

The app perfectly works on S5, but G2 has an error. OS Version of S5 is 6.0.1, and G2 is 4.4.

What should I do for this? I attached build.gradle here.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile files('libs/ajt-2.9.jar', 'libs/javaml-0.1.7.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: do you have a class called PendingCallback?

Comment: No, I don't have PendingCallback class.. It may be one of the classes in GCM.

Comment: so I guess one of your libraries or plugin is using the exact same class with the exact package location.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried what's suggested here:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/3

```
compile ("com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0") {
        exclude module: "play-services-gcm"
}
```

Comment: I just removed jobdispatcher. It works now. Thanks :)